# I want to improve my queryset performance, I am using Pagination to return paginated response in django but its taking so much time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, paginator, django-pagination

here is my pagination code over a queryset.

```
    query_end_time = time.time() - start
    
    print(query_end_time, "query_end_time")

    total_rows = query_set.count()

    number_of_pages = 0

    paginator = Paginator(query_set, number_of_rows)

    number_of_pages = paginator.num_pages

    page_number = request.GET.get("page_number")

    order_item = list(paginator.get_page(page_number))

    pagination_end_time = time.time() - start

    print(pagination_end_time, "pagination_end_time")
```

query time and pagination time
[image: query time and pagination time]

tried django pagination document but not landed to any conclusion

Comment: Show your actual query and relevant models?

Comment: query is working perfectly well as you can see in the query output. i am using select_related,values, filter, order_by and distinct to retrive dataset